# Getting the Error "Required option '-K, --private-key KEY' missing (-h for usage)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

I am using an Ubuntu 12.04. I have downloaded the EC2 CLI tools from the Amazon website. The following are the steps that I have done..

Unzipped the file and put it in a directory.
Set the Java class path properly (My Tomcat is working).

Set the EC2 home path, after that set the EC2 Home and bin path in bashrc

Set the access and secret key in bashrc.

When I am trying to trying to start an instance or do anything for that matter from the terminal, I am getting the error

Required option '-K, --private-key KEY' missing (-h for usage)

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this so it might be helpful for others. The problem was happening because when I installed Ubuntu I had installed the ec2-tools using the apt-get from terminal.

This version of ec2 which Ubuntu has is an outdated version (it was last updated in 2011).
When I found this out, I removed it. And reconfigured the path to the current version of ec2 cli tools I had downloaded and it worked!!! :)

The way to install newer versions of the ec2-api-tools, as suggested by https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EC2StartersGuide, is to simply add the aws-tools PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:awstools-dev/awstools
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then a simple `apt-get install ec2-api-tools` will install the correct version. :)

Comment: @hithwen I agree, so I've edited the answer to include what worked for me.